# Outputting date of next business quarter and count

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have the following code below that is intended to provide two things. A count of days until the next business quarter and the date of the next business quarter. This worked for Q3, but since it started showing Q4, the results are off.

You will see that the date shows the start of the next month. That is intended. It serves as the starting point for the next quarter.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```js
var today = new Date();
var quarter = Math.floor((today.getMonth() + 3) / 3);
var nextQ;
if (quarter == 4) {
  nextQ = new Date (today.getFullYear() + 1, 1, 1);
} else {
  nextQ = new Date (today.getFullYear(), quarter * 3, 1);
}
var millis1 = today.getTime();
var millis2 = nextQ.getTime();
var dayDiff = (millis2 - millis1) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
dayDiffRound = Math.floor(dayDiff);
$('#nextDrawingCount').text(dayDiffRound);
var drawingDate = nextQ.toLocaleString('en-us', {  weekday: 'long' }) + ", " + nextQ.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }) + " " + ("0" + nextQ.getDate()).slice(-2) + ", " + nextQ.getFullYear();
$('#nextDrawing').text(drawingDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="dGw">The next drawing is <span id="nextDrawingCount"></span> days from now (<span id="nextDrawing"></span>).</p>
```

Comment: `nextQ = new Date (today.getFullYear() + 1, 1, 1)` should probably set the month to 0 (January), not 1 (February).

Comment: @RobG Right. How could I do that though?

Comment: `nextQ = new Date (today.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1)`

Comment: @RobG Thanks! That worked. Feel free to leave an answer. Could you explain how that set the month to 0? I found most of this code on a stack question and don't know how the nextQ came up with the actual next quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECMAScript months are zero indexed, so if *quarter* is 4:

```
if (quarter == 4) {
  nextQ = new Date (today.getFullYear() + 1, 1, 1);
```

and *nextQ* is set to 1 February, not 1 January. So change the month index to 0:

```
if (quarter == 4) {
  nextQ = new Date (today.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1);
```

to get 1 January.

The *else* branch works because in:

```
  nextQ = new Date (today.getFullYear(), quarter * 3, 1);
```

if *quarter* is say 2, then the month is set to 6, which is July or the start of your quarter 3.

However, you don't have to treat Q4 any differently, because if *quarter* is 4, then 3x4 is 12 and the date will automatically roll over to the next year (i.e. it will become January of the following year), e.g.:

```js
function getNextQuarter(today = new Date()) {
  var quarter = Math.floor((today.getMonth() + 3) / 3);
  return new Date (today.getFullYear(), quarter * 3, 1);
}

[new Date(),         // current date
 new Date(2019,5,1), // 1 June 2019
 new Date(2019,11,1) // 1 December 2019
].forEach(d => console.log(`${d.toDateString()} => ${getNextQuarter(d).toDateString()}`));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Does it make more sense to change `if (quarter == 4) {` to `if (quarter == 3) {` or just leave it how it is? I don't get why the quarter was ever set to 4 when it is only three months long.

Comment: @Paul—just use it per the answer, there's no need for an *if* to deal with any quarter differently to the others.